# Is it possible to change the electron icon and visible application name dynamically?

Tags: electron

I have a macOS application that currently uses 2 separate instances of electron builds for 2 different "views". The code between the electron apps is almost identical other than different icons, different name and they go to different URLs.

Is it possible for me to build just 1 electron application and dynamically change the icon and visible (to the user) application name so I can reduce the install footprint?

I only need to support macOS.

**EDIT: (to make it more clear)**

I have an app that essentially uses electron as a webview component to 2 portals.

So when I deploy I have 1 electron "app" running as "FOO" with a Foo icon and 1 electron "app" running as "BAR" with a Bar icon.

But all I'm doing under the covers is pointing Foo and Bar to a specific URLs.

I just need it to look to the user like it's 2 separate applications with separate icons.

Comment: at least for the icon, I'm guessing you would know which build you want on startup? Can you just have both icons installed with the application and then select the right one when you're about to create the BrowserWindow? Not sure about how to change the name though. I think that's shoved into the metadata of the packaged up application

Comment: @pushkin I edited the question to expand. Is it possible to have multiple icons for 1 app? I could probably live with the same name if the icons were different.

Comment: does my comment not answer your question? You can just set different icons on the BrowserWindow depending on which "mode" you're in

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regarding the Icon:**

You can change the Electron application/dock icon on macOS using the JavaScript: `dock.setIcon(image)`. For example:

```js
const nativeImage = require('electron').nativeImage
const image = nativeImage.createFromPath('icon.png')
app.dock.setIcon(image);
```

Using the single Electron app, you could open 2 instances of the app (`open -n -a "APPLICATION NAME"`) and change the icon based on the view.

There are more interesting things you can do with the dock on macOS, like `setBadge()`. See https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/dock.md

---

**Regarding the Application Name:**

I do not see a way to do this directly. However, you could get creative and combine the approach above with two very lite 'parent' apps that launch your Electron app as hidden using `app.setActivationPolicy('accessory')` in your `main.js`

See https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/app.md

Comment: This works! The icon does change with this.

Answer (score -1):

You can set both icon and title when initializing your `BrowserWindow`. Use the same logic you use to point Foo or Bar and set `icon` and `title` accordingly.

See the doc -
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. The way I read it @spartygw needs the dock icon and app name (as it appears in the hot-swap / switch app view) to be different. The issue seems to the related to the fact that he has 2 apps that are 95% the same but require the large electron frameworks to be duplicated in each.

Comment: @hokielife, spot on. I tried what assaf said but it doesn't work. The icon doesn't change and the title of the app in the command-tab task list doesn't change. The window title does change, however.